# Microsoft Graph API: Httpclient 403 Forbidden error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, dotnet-httpclient

I am having a C# MVC web application through which I'm trying to read the user's group using Microsoft Graph API. But when I'm trying to do so through code using HttpClient I'm getting "403 Forbidden" error.
I have all the required permissions but still getting the error, can't get the reason for the error or any solution for it. I even tried to google it but couldn't find anything.

If anyone can help.

```
 try
            {
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(HttpClientHelper.GetWinHttpHandler()))
                {
                    var json = @"{ 'securityEnabledOnly': true }";

                    var stringContent = new StringContent(json);

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + graphapitoken);
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/");
                    var response = Task.Run(() => httpClient.PostAsync($"v1.0/users/" + UsermailId + "/getMemberGroups", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")));
                    response.Wait();

                    if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string strResponse = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        object dec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponse);
                        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(dec.ToString());
                        List<JToken> obj1 = obj["value"].ToList();
                        listAssociatedGroups = obj1.Values<string>().ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Getting Token

```
 public class Token
{
    public static string GetToken()
    {
        return GraphToken(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"]);
    }
    private static string GraphToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId);
        
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", credential).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); 
        return result.AccessToken;

    }

    public static string TokenAsync(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, string resourceURI)
    {
        try
        {
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}");

            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

            var authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, credential).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to retrive AAD token");
        }
    }
}
```

API Permissions I have

[image]

Comment: Go to Azure portal>App registrations>API permissions and provide screenshots.

Comment: For the **/users** endpoint, it usually does not require a user to log in, so you need to grant **application permissions** to your application and grant administrator consent. You can use the client credential flow to request tokens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions

Comment: @CarlZhao my application is in Microsoft production Tenant and do have admin consent for the API permissions in Microsoft Tenant. And I'm also getting the correct access token and I have verified that from Graph Explorer as well. I'm getting "Forbidden" error while calling "PostAsync" method or any other method of HTTPCLIENT.

Comment: You need **application permissions**, not **delegated permissions**, because you do not log in as a user, so these delegated permissions are useless to you, so please grant **application permissions** to your application

Comment: As I said in the comment, **For the `/users` endpoint, it usually does not require a user to log in.**

Comment: @CarlZhao Thanks, sure I'll add application permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could test this API with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) directly.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

[image]

I'm not sure which kind of flows that you used to get access token in your code. If you use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#application-permissions), you need to add one of the application permissions. Delegated permissions can be used for the other flows.

[image]

Comment: I'm also getting the correct access token and I have verified that from Graph Explorer as well.I have tested this API with Graph Explorer and getting correct response. I'm getting "Forbidden" error while calling "PostAsync" method or any other method of HTTPCLIENT.

Comment: Hi, @Rupali. Could you provide the screenshot of your permissions? And please tell me which flow you use in the code?

Comment: I have edited my question and have added the screenshot and code for getting token. I'm using client secret.

Comment: @Rupali You have given delegated permissions, but call the API with client credentials. As I said in my reply, you need to add one of the **application permissions**. Delegated permissions only apply when you make calls on behalf of a user.

Comment: Thanks, for helping. I'll raise admin consent for these permissions as well.

Comment: Yes. You need to grant admin consent for your tenant after adding the application permission.

Comment: I need one more help Is there any way I can get the access token without using Client secret ?

Comment: Yes, see the other flows here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark:
Some of those permissions require **admin consent**.
Does your application have admin consent for those permissions?

Comment: Yes I do have the admin consent for the permissions.